# RXJS split by id and process in sequence for each id

Tags: rxjs

Problem: Game: So I have some ships that can arrive to many planets. If the 2 ships arrive at the same time on the new planet can lead to the same process of changing ownership twice. This process is asynchronous and should only happen once per planet ownership change.

To fix this I want split the stream of ships by planet id so each stream will be for only one planet. Now the tricky part is that each ship should only be processed after the previous one has been processed.

- Ships$
- Split by planet id

  - planet id1: process in sequence
  - planet id2: process in sequence
  - ...

Here is some code that will show how it should behave.

```
const ships = [
  {
    id: 1,
    planetId: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    planetId: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    planetId: 2,
  },
  // ... never finishes 
]
// the source observable never finishes 
const source$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(ships.length),
  map(i => ships[i]),
)

const createSubject = (ship) => {
  // Doesn't need to be a subject, but needs to emit new items after a bit of time based on some other requests.
  console.log(`>>>`, ship.id);
  const subject = new Subject();
  setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next(ship.id + ' a' + new Date());
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next(ship.id + ' b' + new Date());
    subject.complete();
  }, 2000);
  return subject.asObservable();
}

// The result should be the following (t, is the time in seconds, t3, is time after 3 seconds)
// t0: >>> 1
// t0: >>> 3
// t1: 1 a
// t1: 2 a
// t2: 1 b
// t2: 2 b
// t2: >>> 2 (note that the second ship didn't call the createSubject until the first finished)
// t3: 1 a
// t4: 1 2
```

## Solution (with a lot of help from A.Winnen and some figuring out)

Run it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zopfk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
  const ships = [
    {
      id: 1,
      planetId: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      planetId: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      planetId: 2,
    }
  ];
  const createSubject = (ship) => {
    console.log(ship.id + ' a')
    const subject = new Subject();
    setTimeout(() => {
      //subject.next(ship.id + ' b');
    }, 500);//
    setTimeout(() => {
      subject.next(ship.id + ' c');
      subject.complete();//
    }, 1000);
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
  let x = 0;
  interval(10).pipe(//
    take(ships.length),
    map(i => ships[i]),
    groupBy(s => s.planetId),
    mergeMap(group$ => {//
      x++
      return group$.pipe(
        tap(i => console.log('x', i, x)),
        concatMap(createSubject)
      )
    }),
  ).subscribe(res => console.log('finish', res), undefined, () => console.log("completed"))
```

How can this be done in rxjs?

Code:

```
  const shipArriveAction$ = action$.pipe<AppAction>(
    ofType(ShipActions.arrive),
    groupBy(action => action.payload.ship.toPlanetId),
    mergeMap((shipByPlanet$: Observable<ShipActions.Arrive>) => {
      return shipByPlanet$.pipe(
        groupBy(action => action.payload.ship.id),
        mergeMap((planet$) => {
          return planet$.pipe(
            concatMap((action) => {
              console.log(`>>>concat`, new Date(), action);
              // this code should be called in sequence for each ship with the same planet. I don't need only the results to be in order, but also this to be called in sequence.
              const subject = new Subject();
              const pushAction: PushAction = (pushedAction) => {
                subject.next(pushedAction);
              };
              onShipArriveAction(state$.value, action, pushAction).then(() => {
                subject.complete();
              });
              return subject.asObservable();
            }),
          )
        })
      );

    )
  ;
```

The code from A.Winnen is very close, but only works with a source observable that is finished, not continuous:

```
    const ships = [
      {
        id: 1,
        planetId: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        planetId: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        planetId: 2,
      }
    ];
    const createSubject = (ship) => {
      console.log(ship.id + ' a')
      const subject = new Subject();
      setTimeout(() => {
        subject.next(ship.id + ' b');
      }, 1000);//
      setTimeout(() => {
        subject.next(ship.id + ' c');
        subject.complete();//
      }, 2000);
      return subject.asObservable().pipe(
        finalize(null)
      );
    }

    interval(1000).pipe(
      take(ships.length),
      tap(console.log),
      map(i => ships[i]),
      groupBy(s => s.planetId),
      mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
      mergeMap(group => from(group).pipe(
        concatMap(createSubject)
      ))
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res), undefined, () => console.log("completed"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a combination of groupBy and mergeMap to achieve your goal.

```js
from(ships).pipe(
  groupBy(ship => ship.planetId),
  mergeMap(planetGroup => planetGroup.pipe(
    concatMap(ship => {
      // do real processing in this step
     return of(`planetGroup: ${planetGroup.key} - processed ${ship.ship}`);
    })
  ))
).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

I made a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6etaja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

EDIT:
updated blitzstack: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7znvk

Comment: Thanks, but in the "// do real processing in this step" I need to send more actions out. The `of` will be replaced with a subject that emits 5 actions during 5 seconds, then finishes.

Comment: can you provide a blitzstack with a snippet of your actual code? 
If you want to wait for the 5 actions emitted by the subject to complete before the next planet is processed, you could add another concat operator like i edited it in my answer

Comment: Thanks, here is a simple example, but doesn't work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOwPxb?editors=0012

Comment: I updated the question, but I think is not possible to do with concat at all.

Comment: yes, you are right. the stream completes early when the first groupedObservable completes.
I added another blitzstack example. It should work as described in your updated question.

Comment: Wow, thanks that looks great! Do you know why `>>> 2` happens before `Ship 1 completed!`, how can we make it to wait until `Ship 1 completed!` is really finished?

Comment: Actually doesn't really matter much, but that code is quite hard  to digest. How can I make it a bit simpler or that's it? :)

Comment: i don't really know why the "complete" logging is before the ">>>" logging
Maybe some scheduling magic :)
Honestly, that code is not that hard. I've seem much more complicated pipes in some projects. I guess that's it ;)

Comment: Actually after implementing in my code it doesn't work as expected. The code assumes that all items are received in one go, when it actually receives them at separate times, I put here the example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zopfk?file=src/app/app.component.ts Sorry again for coming back

Comment: So basically the problem is that the code only starts to process after all initial items are received, but in my real code there is always new ships.